# Transferring Data from a Form to a django View

Tags: django, django-forms, django-filter

I have a form:

```
class GenereteReport (forms.ModelForm):
    olddate = DateField (widget = forms.DateInput (attrs = {'type': 'date'}))
    newdate = DateField (widget = forms.DateInput (attrs = {'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = ['typeOper', 'category']
```

I need to select data from a database ranging from olddate to newdate

```
class ChartData (APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get (self, request, format = None):
        labels = []
        default_items = []
        transacts = Transactions.objects.all ()
        for transact in transacts:
            labels.append (transact.category.name)
            default_items.append (int (transact.suma))
        data = {
            "labels": labels,
            "default": default_items,
        }
        return response (data)
```

model

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    typeOper = models.ForeignKey(TypeOperation, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    suma = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10000, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)



    def __str__(self):
        return "Category {0}".format(self.category)
```

what to do instead of `transacts = Transactions.objects.all ()` to select data in the date range that is in the form from the base
link to the repository https://github.com/IvanYukish/PersonalFinanceManager

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. could you please post your `transactions` model?

Comment: model added to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, in your `get` function, you're going to need to add code to handle the form correctly and get the two cleaned, validated dates from the form.  This piece of django documentation shows how to do that: [django working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#the-view)

Once you check that the form is valid, you will have access to `form.cleaned_data`, which is a dictionary containing all cleaned fields from the form.  `old_date = form.cleaned_data['olddate']` will get you the first date in your form, likewise for the second.
Once you have those, you can then `filter` your transactions like this: `Transactions.objects.filter(created__gte=olddate, created_lte=newdate)`. This says, show me all transactions that have a `created` date greater than or equal to the `olddate`, and less than or equal to the `newdate`.